# How to read full multipart stream in Warp?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-warp

I am trying to build a simple web server to upload and save images using Rust. Here is my code:

```
use std::convert::Infallible;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use warp::multipart::FormData;
use warp::{http::StatusCode, Filter};
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let upload_route = warp::path("upload")
        .and(warp::post())
        .and(warp::multipart::form().max_length(3 * 1024 * 1024))
        .and_then(upload_handler);

    let hello_route = warp::path!("hello")
        .and(warp::get())
        .and(warp::fs::file("./static/index.html"));

    let routes = upload_route.or(hello_route);

    println!("Server started at http://localhost:8080");
    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8080)).await;
}

async fn upload_handler(mut form: FormData) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, Infallible> {
    while let Ok(Some(part)) = form.try_next().await {
        let filename = match part.filename() {
            Some(filename) => filename.to_string(),
            None => return Ok(StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST),
        };
        println!("Receiving file: {}", filename);

        let mut data = Vec::new();
        let mut stream = part.stream();
        
        while let Ok(Some(chunk)) = stream.try_next().await {
            data.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
        }

        let save_path = PathBuf::from(format!("./uploads/{}", filename));
        if let Err(_) = tokio::fs::write(save_path, data).await {
            return Ok(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    Ok(StatusCode::CREATED)
}
```

My problem is in line `data.extend_from_slice(&chunk);`:

```
expected `&[_]`, found `&impl Buf`
```

I am not exactly sure what `[_]` means and why `data.extend_from_slice` does not accept the `chunk` bytes.

Comment: `[_]` is a slice (extend_from_**slice**), `chunk` is not a slice. (Aside: saving to a user-provided filename is usually best avoided when possible. From a quick look through the warp/multer source code, I didn’t see anything that would stop `part.filename()` from being `../../etc/passwd`, i.e. a path traversal vulnerability.)

Comment: Looks like you can call `reader` to get something that implements `Read`. Then you can call `read_to_end(&mut data)`. If that works, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Ry Thanks for that clarification, I'm still not quite clear on how I can convert my chunks to a slice? It's my understanding that chunks are an iterator over a slice, so I guess I'm confused why chunk here is a Buf? Thanks, the path traversal vulnerability is clear to me now.

Comment: @drewtato can you give me a little more guidance on that? Are you suggesting I use BufReader to read each chunk? `data` is already read and ready to be written to disk, so do you mean I call read_to_end on stream?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reader`](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.1.0/bytes/buf/trait.Buf.html#method.reader) to create an implementer of [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html), and then call [`read_to_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end).

```rs
while let Ok(Some(mut chunk)) = stream.try_next().await {
    chunk.reader().read_to_end(&mut data).unwrap();
}
```

The issue with [`chunk`](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.1.0/bytes/buf/trait.Buf.html#tymethod.chunk) is that it doesn't have to return the entire buffer.

> Note that this can return shorter slice

If you want to use `chunk`, you have to loop until [`remaining`](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.1.0/bytes/buf/trait.Buf.html#tymethod.remaining) is zero.

```rs
while let Ok(Some(mut chunk)) = stream.try_next().await {
    while chunk.remaining() > 0 {
        let slice: &[u8] = chunk.chunk();
        data.extend_from_slice(slice);
        chunk.advance(slice.len());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address this type error using the Buf `chunk` method like so

```
while let Ok(Some(mut chunk)) = stream.try_next().await {
    let slice: &[u8] = chunk.chunk();
    data.extend_from_slice(slice);
    chunk.advance(slice.len());
}
```